# Node.js and SQL connection issues

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Hello this is my first time working with Node.js and SQL as i am usually much more of a PHP or HTML person and I'm only 13. I also use an online compiler called Repl.it and it seems to work most of the time but i think that might have something to do with it.

Anyway I'm trying to build a login page for my website that i am working on and I need a database and a way to communicate to the database. The only (easy) way i could find to do this is with Node and SQL. I downloaded a package called "mysql" and that seemed to work fine however when i go into my node file and test the connection i keep getting errors all over the place and i'm not sure if its the code or the compiler.

Here is the link to my code.

https://repl.it/@notyourgroup/new-web#.replit

here is some of the code in the Node file.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "username",
  pasword: "password"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

There are several errors when i run this code and i think that it is my compiler being dumb or me not being an admin. I cant find anywhere that gives me a good solid answer so I came to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First set up a local database on your PC if not set up already and pass the database key in the createConnection object with a valid user and password.

```
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "username",
    pasword: "password",
    database: "my_db",
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the input unfortunately i dont think it did too much